# Are there any thriving communities among the Stack Exchange clones?

Tags: discussion, clone

There is a large [list of Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones), but it is very hard to find thriving communities (ie. low spam rate, high answer quality and good answer rate).

I think that seeing how these communities operate could provide insights into other approaches for running a Q&A site. We would be able to see the effects of different policies without necessarily having to experiment with them ourselves.

What thriving communities are based on the Stack Exchange model?

Comment: [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net) isn't really a clone (it's still on SE1.0!) but it's probably one of the best successes outside of the network.

Comment: [ask sql server central](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/index.html) seems to be doing OK AFAIK.

Comment: Haha yes, Math Overflow is an amusing case, given the recent ruckus about "draconian moderation policies" here.

Comment: @CodyGray: Yes, MathOverflow's moderation is as draconian as it gets.  It seems to work for them, though.

Comment: [Draw 3 cards](http://draw3cards.com/) for Magic the Gathering seems to be going quite well too. There may be a few other SE 1.0 sites that have managed to maintain an active community

Comment: @CodyGray: And here is the draconian moderation again

Answer (score 1):

[Fedora](http://ask.fedoraproject.org/questions) - 1236 questions

Comment: "First time here? Check out the FAQ!" No link to be found :D

Comment: @minitech: The FAQ link is at the bottom. (Gah, why does *nobody* read the FAQ?!) I must say, their "search" box is much more inviting than the one on SO. Nice and obvious and autofocused.

Comment: Looks like [Askbot](http://askbot.org/en/questions/).

Comment: Nobody votes on questions there.

Comment: The *really* nice thing about that search box is that it doesn't autoexpand...

Comment: @mog And... I just learned that SO has a search box.

Comment: @todofixthis - Note the "Powered by Askbot" notice in AskFedora's footer...

Answer (score 1):

[Openstreetmap](http://help.openstreetmap.org/) (OSM) runs on a Q&A clone. In my experience, the quality of content seems to be poor in certain areas.

Comment: GIS is actually an official SE site, not a clone.

Comment: @Diago: I know, I meant to say it's the nearest SE site to OSM that is official. Although GIS doesn't have as many OSM questions.